# Proving that if $C_0(X)$ is unital, then $X$ is compact

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Apologies if this is simple, I'm having one of those days. Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and $C_0(X)$ be the commutative $C^*$-algebra of continuous complex-valued functions on $X$ that *vanish at infinity* i.e. for which $\lbrace x\in X:|f(x)|\geq\epsilon\rbrace$ is compact for each $\epsilon>0$.

If $x\mapsto 1$ is in $C_0(X)$ then it is clear that $X$ is compact. So all I need to show is that for unital $C_0(X)$, its identity must be the constant function $1$.

Assuming $C_0(X)$ to be unital, there exists $e\in C_0(X)$ with $\|e\|_\infty=1$ for which $fe=ef=f$ for all $f\in C_0(X)$. Substituting $f=e$ gives that $e(x)=0$ or $e(x)=1$ for each $x$ and $\|e\|_\infty=1$ then gives that $e(x_1)=1$ for some $x_1$.

If $e$ is not the constant function $1$, then $e(x_0)=0$ for some $x_0$ and so $X$ is disconnected. Also, since $e$ vanishes at infinity, $\lbrace x\in X:e(x)=1\rbrace$ is compact. I'm sure I've missed something obvious; how do I show that $e$ is the constant function $1$?

Comment: I'm not well-versed in topology, but under your assumptions on $X$, could you maybe use something like Urysohn's lemma to build "bump" functions around every given $x\in X$? This would give $e(x)=1$.

Comment: Use Urysohn's Lemma to show that for every $x\in X$ there is a function $f:X\to \mathbb C$ with $f(x)=1.$ Then $e(x)=e(x)\cdot 1=e(x)f(x)=f(x)=1$

Comment: @D. Brogan Urysohn's Lemma (in the form I have seen it in at least) assumes that the topological space is normal. Compact Hausdorff spaces are normal, but I don't think they are for locally compact, necessarily.

Comment: @thewonderfulwizardofoz: Urysohn works on locally compact + Hausdorff.

Comment: @MartinArgerami There is a locally compact Hausdorff version described in below link but it is different to the usual one, is this what you are referring to? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3398140/can-i-apply-urysohns-lemma-on-a-locally-compact-hausdorff-space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $e\in C_0(X)$ be an identity and fix any $x_0\in X$. We will show that $e(x_0)=1$, whence $e=1$.

Since $X$ is locally compact, there is a neigbhourhood $K$ of $x_0$ which is compact, and so it is closed because $X$ is Hausdorff. Moreover, since $X$ is Hausdorff, $K$ is compact Hausdorff, and thus it is normal. Let $F$ be the boundary of $K$. Since $K$ is closed, $F\subseteq K$.

Now, $F$ and $\{x_0\}$ are closed in $K$, so by Urysohn's lemma, there is a continuous real-valued $f\colon K\to \mathbf R$ such that $f(x_0)=1$ and $f$ vanishes on $F$. But then $f$ can be extended to $\bar f\colon X\to \mathbf R$ which vanishes outside of $K$.

Finally, it is easy to see that $\bar f$ is continuous, and it is compactly supported, so it clearly is in $C_0(X)$. Since $\bar f\cdot e(x_0)=1=\bar f(x_0)$, it follows that $e(x_0)=1$.